# Multisite on Sitecore Managed Cloud Azure CDN

Tags: azure, multisite, cdn, sitecore-managed-cloud

I have a `Sitecore 10.2 version multisite project`. Example: Site1 and Site2 and it's deployed on Sitecore MCS. It's perfectly working fine with `https://site1.com` and `https://site2.com` on `MCS non-prod environment`
(**note:** CDN does not exist in the non-prod environment)

In Prod, environment CDN exists and I have mapped `www.site2.com to CDN`. So when the user will hit the Site2 request goes to the CDN and take the data from the CD server. Later I will write a redirect rule for the `htts://site2.com` to `www.site2.com`.

Now when I hit `https://site2.com` and it perfectly works and serves me the content of the site2.

When I request with `www.site2.com` it populates the content and pages of `site1 instead of site2`.

**In theory:**

There are 2 domains for Site2:

1. https://Site2.com (CD Server)
2. [www.Site2.com](http://www.Site2.com) (CDN endpoint)

**Site2.com**
This is the apex (naked) domain. It has been pointed to the CD server `(mc-********-****-****-****-****-cd)`. All users who enter this domain will reach the CD server and will need to be immediately redirected to `www.Site2.com` using permanent 301 redirects.

**[www.Site2.com](http://www.Site2.com)**
This sub-domain is the main domain for Site2. This custom domain is mapped to the CDN endpoint `(mc-********-****-****-****-****-cdn-endpoint)` and hence all cacheable assets are cached and served through Azure CDN.

My Site Node code is:

```
            <site name="site2" patch:after="site[@name='website']"
              hostName="www.site2.com|site2.com"
              targetHostName="www.site2.com"
              scheme="https"
              ...........
              rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site2"
              startItem="/Home"
              database="web"
              domain="extranet"
              />
    </sites>
```

Does anyone encountered the same issue, please guide me.

Comment: What have you set the "origin" to be for your azure CDN? Also is there a domain mapped to the "website" site? If so try setting origin to website domain + site2 home path. I.e. site1.com/sitecore/content/site2/home

Comment: Origin hostname for Azure CDN is my CD server: https://mc-********-****-****-****-****-cd.azurewebsites.net. There is only 1 CM and 1 CD server. I have mapped site2.com domain to the website CD Server. And www.site2.com domain is mapped to the CDN.

Comment: So to confirm the website site node is mapped to site2.com on cd server? Ie. <site name="website" hostname="site2.com"> ?

Comment: no that is to site1.com. <site name="website" hostname="site1.com"> and another one <site name="site2" hostname="site2.com">

Answer (score 1):

This is what I believe is happening.

You have two domains hosted on Sitecore instance. Both domains have IIS bindings added to the IIS instance that is running your Sitecore instance.

In a non CDN situation, a request comes to IIS for site2.com. This is then passed on to Sitecore with the information that the request is for site2.com. Your `<site name="site2">` node, recognises the incoming domain and sitecore serves data from that site configuration.

In a CDN situation, a request is made to the CDN. CDN doesnt have data, so refers back to origin domain for data. The CDN then sends a request to IIS instance on domain your-cd.azurewebsites.net. Non of your site nodes have a mapping for `<site xxxx hostName = "your-cd.azurewebsites.net">`. So Sitecore defaults to the "website" site node and send information back for that site configuration.

You could try adding a hostName entry on your site2 node for `"your-cd.azurewebsites.net"` or set origin on CDN to `"your-cd.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/content/Site2"` . However, this would cause you problems with site1.

I think your only solution might be to create a second CDN which is specifically for site2.com. Set the origin for that to be `"your-cd.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/content/Site2"`.

Comment: You could try adding a hostName entry on your site2 node for "your-cd.azurewebsites.net" or set origin on CDN to "your-cd.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/content/Site2" . However, this would cause you problems with site1.   ===> Yes, it will cause an issue for my Site1.

Comment: I think your only solution might be to create a second CDN which is specifically for site2.com. Set the origin for that to be "your-cd.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/content/Site2".    ==> Client dependency, does not want to purchase

Comment: Thanks for more explanation :)